# Submit a XML request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, request

I am trying to get information from an API. I would like to be able to get the "Location:" property from the API response and capture it as a variable in PHP.

Here is a snip from the API docs so you know what I am talking about:

> > Read Person Portrait This example request illustrates how to read a description of the portrait for a tree person.
>
> XML Request
>
> GET /platform/tree/persons/KWWM-5R1/portrait 
>   Accept: application/x-fs-v1+xml 
>   Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
>   Response
>
> HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect 
>   Transfer-encoding: chunked
>   Cache-control: no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0 
>   Content-type: application/x-fs-v1+xml 
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding 
>   Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Expect 
>   Location: /domain/path/to/image 
>   X-processing-time: 1 
>   Content-location: /platform/tree/persons/PPPP-PPP/portrait

I would like to return and capture the Location: value (path to image) as a PHP variable so I can use it as an image source.

I have tried using cURL from another help site but that doesn't return anything (not even an error)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  // set url, timeouts, encoding headers etc.
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.familysearch.org/platform/tree/persons/KWWM-5R1/portrait,
  // ...
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: Bearer' . $_SESSION['fs-session'],
  'Accept: application/x-fs-v1+xml',

));

$respons = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

I apologize for asking for too much help, but I am very new to this and was up all night trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you simply want to get the response headers of a request ?
You could use this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php